# Robot battle game Terminal game code

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, console

This is a project for a class and all the requirements are met, I just wanted to do a little more and make this even better. All the changes that I've made are already implemented and I would like to know what could I do more.

I tried doing some changes here and there but could not think of anything substantial to change. I also want to implement a CPU vs player function. I also tried to make classes of robot in the game but it always gave me an error that I did not know how to solve.

```
robot_art = r"""  #ascii art of the robot#
      0: {head_name}
      Is available: {head_status}
      Attack: {head_attack}                              
      Defense: {head_defense}
      Energy consumption: {head_energy_consump}
              ^
              |                  |1: {weapon_name}
              |                  |Is available: {weapon_status}
     ____     |    ____          |Attack: {weapon_attack}
    |oooo|  ____  |oooo| ------> |Defense: {weapon_defense}
    |oooo| '    ' |oooo|         |Energy consumption: {weapon_energy_consump}
    |oooo|/\_||_/\|oooo|          
    `----' / __ \  `----'           |2: {left_arm_name}
   '/  |#|/\/__\/\|#|  \'           |Is available: {left_arm_status}
   /  \|#|| |/\| ||#|/  \           |Attack: {left_arm_attack}
  / \_/|_|| |/\| ||_|\_/ \          |Defense: {left_arm_defense}
 |_\/    O\=----=/O    \/_|         |Energy consumption: {left_arm_energy_consump}
 <_>      |=\__/=|      <_> ------> |
 <_>      |------|      <_>         |3: {right_arm_name}
 | |   ___|======|___   | |         |Is available: {right_arm_status}
// \\ / |O|======|O| \  //\\        |Attack: {right_arm_attack}
|  |  | |O+------+O| |  |  |        |Defense: {right_arm_defense}
|\/|  \_+/        \+_/  |\/|        |Energy consumption: {right_arm_energy_consump}
\__/  _|||        |||_  \__/        
      | ||        || |          |4: {left_leg_name} 
     [==|]        [|==]         |Is available: {left_leg_status}
     [===]        [===]         |Attack: {left_leg_attack}
      >_<          >_<          |Defense: {left_leg_defense}
     || ||        || ||         |Energy consumption: {left_leg_energy_consump}
     || ||        || || ------> |
     || ||        || ||         |5: {right_leg_name}
   __|\_/|__    __|\_/|__       |Is available: {right_leg_status}
  /___n_n___\  /___n_n___\      |Attack: {right_leg_attack}
                                |Defense: {right_leg_defense}
                                |Energy consumption: {right_leg_energy_consump}
                                
"""

colors = {
        "black": '\x1b[90m',
        "blue": '\x1b[94m',
        "cyan": '\x1b[96m',
        "green": '\x1b[92m',
        "magenta": '\x1b[95m',
        "red": '\x1b[91m',
        "white": '\x1b[97m',
        "yellow":'\x1b[93m',
    }

class Part():
    
    def __init__(self, name: str, attack_level=0, defense_level=0, energy_consumption=0):
        self.name = name
        self.attack_level = attack_level
        self.defense_level = defense_level
        self.energy_consumption = energy_consumption
        
    def get_status_dict(self):
        formatted_name = self.name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
        return {
            "{}_name".format(formatted_name): self.name.upper(),
            "{}_status".format(formatted_name): self.is_available(),
            "{}_attack".format(formatted_name): self.attack_level,
            "{}_defense".format(formatted_name): self.defense_level,
            "{}_energy_consump".format(formatted_name): self.energy_consumption,
        }

    def reduce_edefense(self, attack_level):
        self.defense_level = self.defense_level - attack_level
        if self.defense_level <= 0:
            self.defense_level = 0

    def is_available(self):
        return self.defense_level <= 0

class Robot:
               #definitions of the robot and it's parts#
    def __init__(self, name, color_code):
        self.name = name
        self.color_code = color_code
        self.energy = 100
        self.parts = [
            Part("Head", attack_level=5, defense_level=10, energy_consumption=5),
            Part("Weapon", attack_level=15, defense_level=0, energy_consumption=10),
            Part("Left Arm", attack_level=3, defense_level=20, energy_consumption=10),
            Part("Right Arm", attack_level=6, defense_level=20, energy_consumption=10),
            Part("Left Leg", attack_level=4, defense_level=20, energy_consumption=15),
            Part("Right Leg", attack_level=8, defense_level=20, energy_consumption=15),
        ]
    

    def print_status(self):
        print(self.color_code)
        str_robot = robot_art.format(**self.get_part_status())
        self.greet()
        self.print_energy()
        print(str_robot)
        print(colors["white"])
    

    def greet(self):
        print("Hello, my name is", self.name)
    

    def print_energy(self):
        print("We have", self.energy, " percent energy left")
    

    def get_part_status(self):
        part_status = {}
        for part in self.parts:
            status_dict = part.get_status_dict()
            part_status.update(status_dict)
        return part_status
      

#atk methods of the robot#
    def attack(self, enemy_robot, part_to_use, part_to_attack):
        enemy_robot.parts[part_to_attack].reduce_edefense(self.parts[part_to_use].attack_level) 
        self.energy -= self.parts[part_to_use].energy_consumption
    

#check if a part of the robot is availible to attack#
    def is_there_available_part(self):
        for part in self.parts:
            if part.is_available():
                return True
        return False
    

    def is_on(self):
        return self.energy >= 0

#Name and colorize the robot#
def build_robot():
    robot_name = input("Robot name: ")
    color_code = choose_color()
    robot = Robot(robot_name, color_code)
    robot.print_status()
    return robot

def choose_color():
    available_colors = colors
    print("Available colors:")
    for key, value in available_colors.items():
        print(value, key)
    print(colors["white"])
    chosen_color = input("Choose a color: " )
    color_code = available_colors[chosen_color.lower()]
    return color_code

def play():
    playing = True
    print("Welcome to the game!")
    print("Datas for player 1:")
    robot_one = build_robot()
    print("Datas for player 2:")
    robot_two = build_robot()
    
    current_robot = robot_one
    enemy_robot = robot_two
    rount = 0
    
    while playing:
        if rount % 2 == 0:
            current_robot = robot_one
            enemy_robot = robot_two
        else:
            current_robot = robot_two
            enemy_robot = robot_one
        current_robot.print_status()
        print("What part should I use to attack?:")
        part_to_use = input("Choose a number part: ")
        part_to_use = int(part_to_use)
        
        enemy_robot.print_status()
        print("Which part of the enemy should we attack?")
        part_to_attack = input("Choose a enemy number part to attack: ")
        part_to_attack = int(part_to_attack)
        
        current_robot.attack(enemy_robot, part_to_use, part_to_attack)
        rount += 1
        if not enemy_robot.is_on() or enemy_robot.is_there_available_part() == False:
            playing = False
            print("Congratulations, you won")
play()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Robot should accept everything via constructor - not just name and color, but also energy and the parts. Then build_robot function would create those parts.

This obeys dependency inversion principle which is generally a good practice.

That way you get more flexibility. To name a few examples, the player or the enemy could start with handicap energy, the robot state can be saved to file and loaded later, the player and the enemy can have different stats on the parts, the stats can be randomized a bit, etc. All that without modifying the Robot class.